# QT Breadcrumb Navigation

Tags: c++, qt, widget, breadcrumbs

I would like to add a breadcrumb navigation bar to a QT application. In KDE there is KUrlNavigator which is used by dolphin. Is there a native QT widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

qxtcrumbview in libqxt.org

Not documented, you need to download the source code in order to find this one.

Answer (score 1):

This may be achieved with `QLabel`: There may be multiple links in a single `QLabel`, see `QLabel::openExternalLinks()` and `Qt::TextInteractionFlags`.
Or in more detail:

```
auto label = new QLabel(); 
label->setText(
  "<a href=\"https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html\">"
  "QLabel</a>::"
  "<a href=\"https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#textInteractionFlags-prop\">"
  "textInteractionFlags</a>");
label->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
label->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextBrowserInteraction);
label->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
```

Comment: So you can add multiple html links to the label, use `setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextBrowserInteraction)` and then listen on the `linkActivated` signal to get the clicked entry?